# Optimal Partition Allocation

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB for holding a variety of different document types.

I have read various documentation and am not clear on partition size.

Having many logical partitions across the data has many benefits around performance.  What I don't fully understand is how to determine how many partitions to have.

Are we better to have

- 1 million partitions of 10 records
- 10 partitions of 1 million records

Is there some sweet spot for partition size that we should be targeting?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey has some pointers on how to choose the right partition key.